# Modifying table row content with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Well, this might seem trivial to some, but for the longest time I've been doing the following:

```
    $('table#mats tr:last').find("select[id^='material_type']").val('');
    $('table#mats tr:last').find("select[id^='material_desc']").val('');
    $('table#mats tr:last').find("select[id^='material_thick']").val('');
    $('table#mats tr:last').find("select[id^='material_color']").val('');
    $('table#mats tr:last').find("select[id^='material_finish']").val('');
```

In other words, I'm modifying the values for each input in the last row of my table. I'm looking for a way to do this without repeating too much because this can get overwhelming. But I'm not sure you can chain with `find` and modify something at the same time, or am I wrong? I'm pretty sure there is something in jQuery that allows for this but I cannot remember what it was.

Comment: For questions like this, it's often a good idea (if not entirely mandatory) to provide some sample/representative HTML. In this case, as [Arun P. Johny shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20954001/82548), it *can* be deduced, but deduction is just an educated *guess*, and guessing is usually a bad idea, with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are no other select elements in the tr then why not

```
$('#mats tr:last select").val('');
```

If there are other select elements and you want to reset only these elements then add a common class to all these select elements then

```
$('#mats tr:last select.myclass").val('');
```

If that also is not possible then

```
$('#mats tr:last select").filter('[id^='material_type'],[id^='material_desc'],[id^='material_thick'],[id^='material_color'],[id^='material_finish']').val('');
```

Comment: Would you also be able to use the `end()` method to do this?

Comment: @Dimitri not sure what you want to do with `end()`